# Why does std::partition not have an out-of-place variant?

Tags: c++, algorithm, partition, std

[`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) is nifty, but it is in-place; and [`std::partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) is also nice, but it takes two output iterators, i.e. you have to at least count in advance the number of elements satisfying the predicate if you want to use the same output array. Why isn't there an out-of-place `std::partition`, or a single-output-iterator `std::partition_copy`, in `<algorithm>`?

Comment: What advantage would this have over making your own copy and `std::partition`ing it?

Comment: @user2357112: Performance?... although, I guess you could say that if I care about performance I shouldn't use `<algorithm>` code to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because the functionality can already be attained by either:

- Copying the original container and using in-place `partition`.
- Sizing the single destination container to the correct size and using the `begin()` and `rbegin()` iterators to fill it from the front and back with `partition_copy`.

Comment: Your second suggestion is a clever idea that probably wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: Both suggestions require a lot more time than the combined operation; at the very least you have to iterate the entire input one more time. Would this not be an issue meriting another variant? Also, there already is some redundancy in `<algorithm>`. Are you sure this is the actual reason? Finally, your second suggestion is nice.

Comment: @ein why does `rbegin` solution have that problem?  I cannot think of a reasonable out of place partition that does not basically do the rbegin trick (use output iterators that construct the elements).  You *need* two separate places to write to out of place partition.

Comment: @Yakk: Hmmm... you know what, you're right, taking that back. You don't need to count the number of matching elements.